# static class members in c++

Tags: visual-c++, static, member

I'm trying to take the window making code from NeHe.gamedev.net and turn it into a class so I can use it more easily and I'm running into an issue. The WndProc method needs to be declared as static I read, which of course means the variables used within it need to be static. But when I declare them like this in the header file

```
private:

static bool keys[256];                  //for key events
static bool active;
static bool fullscreen;
```

I get an error saying that they are undeclared externals. I'm rather new with c++ so what is it that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Answered my own question literally seconds later. But just in case I will quote from the site where I found the answer "The declaration of a static data member in the member list of a class is not a definition. You must define the static member outside of the class declaration, in namespace scope." Basically they need to be defined in the .cpp file by saying type classname::membername = something.

Answer (score 2):

Static values must also be declared in an implementation file. In your .cpp file you should have something like:

```
bool MyClass::keys[256];
bool MyClass::active;
bool MyClass::fullscreen;
```

The problem is, without being declared somewhere in an implementation file, the compiler has no good place to put the storage for the static variables.

Comment: Awesome that confirms what I read. I'd upvote you but I can't :(. I did click that this was helpful though.